# How can I run a second command after the first finishes?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I got a script to lookup a value in a config value and replace it with user input. This works fine with only one if statement. But I would like to prompt the user with 3 questions (ask for IP1 => replace value, ask for IP2 => replace value etc.)

Simply copy/pasting the same command and finishing with fi does not work.

Works

```
if read -p "Enter IP1" IP1; then
  sed -i~ -e "s/myip1/${IP1}/g" test.txt
else
  echo Error
fi
```

Doesn't work

```
if read -p "Enter IP1" IP1; then
  sed -i~ -e "s/myip1/${IP1}/g" test.txt
else
  echo Error
if read -p "Enter IP2" IP2; then
  sed -i~ -e "s/myip2/${IP2}/g" test.txt
else
  echo Error
fi
```

Comment: All you need is the fi after the first if statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shells are not whitespace sensitive (unlike, say, Python). `if` statements are terminated by a `fi` command, not by the layout of your code. If you have two `if` statements, you need two `fi`s:

```
if read -p "Enter IP1" IP1; then
  sed -i~ -e "s/myip1/${IP1}/g" test.txt
else
  echo Error
fi   # <<<<<< Added
if read -p "Enter IP2" IP2; then
  sed -i~ -e "s/myip2/${IP2}/g" test.txt
else
  echo Error
fi
```

By the way, you should not use all-caps for variable names, because names is all-caps are conventionally used by the shell and the OS. Your own variables should have lower-case names, so that they don't clash.

Answer (score -1):

Testing this:

```
if read -p "Please Enter an IP" "$ip":'[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$' >/dev/null; then
  echo "success"
else
  echo "fail"
```

Comment: Thanks, adding fi solved the problem. A separate but related question; I know goto doesn't work in bash but what would the equivelant be? Before allowing the user to input the IP I want to ask them if a IP is necessary. If its not then I want it to skip to the next section of the script.

#!/bin/bash
WAN2_prompt
read -p "WAN2 exists?: " -n 1 -r
if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then 
  goto WAN2
else 
  goto WAN3_prompt
fi

Comment: @sjaak wheter the string as a possible to add solved